# TIBCO BW JMS Queue Sender

Tags: queue, jms, tibco, sender, businessworks

I am using JMS Queue Sender pallete to send message through MQ queue to an application which uses MQ interface to read the message and it expects ApplIdentityData and format = 'MQSTR' as part of the MQ header.

Not sure how I can implement it in TIBCO BW; could some please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032020_.htm

If you set a JMS message property with those names you can control the MQMD Header information. For example `msg.setStringProperty("JMS_IBM_Format","777");` would change that format. But if you send a JMS **TextMessage** you should already get the correct MQ Format. Your MQ Application name will be filled in (something derived from Business Works) by the send method. I think the rows with "Set By"  "Send Method" you can't control.